# What prerequisites are required for studying Hochschild homology?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Wondering if it is possible to get enough background to attend a workshop on the topic in a few weeks, especially when the material is aimed at PhDs.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Background: Second year undergraduate, had courses on linear algebra, analysis 1, 2 and 3, group theory (other courses as well but these are the relevant ones).

Self studied rings and modules, basic topology, some amount of commutative algebra, some basic algebraic geometry(varieties)

Comment: Sorry, edited it now.

Comment: Not an expert, but noncommutative algebra and homological algebra will definitely help